# Databricks monitoring a column value in a spark table

Tags: pyspark, databricks

I have a complex workflow (partly inherited) in databricks that runs multiple child notebooks.  Child notebooks should not run if the current run is set to terminated by an external process.  Currently I am checking the state of this column before each run.  There is some pseudo code below that tries to give an idea.  My question is, is there a way to make this read better and make it easier to maintain. A more global if or wait that will check dynamically if the job is "terminated" and move the code on to the tidy up part.

```
audit = spark.createDataFrame([('122','complete',None),
      ('123','complete',None),
      ('124','Processing','Terminated'),
      ('125','Processing',None)],"job_id","job_status","external_status")

audit.write.overwrite("audit")

def is_terminated(run_id):
    current_log = spark.table("audit").filter(f"run_id = {run_id}") 

    job_terminated =current_log.select('external_status').collect()[0][0]

    return(terminated)

run_id = '125' # in live code there is a get current run_id job

terminated = is_terminated(run_id)

if terminated != "Terminated":
    dbutils.notebook.run("./notebooks/job1",0)

terminated = is_terminated(run_id)

otherstuff = otherstuffjob(run_id)

if terminated != "Terminated" and otherstuff == True:
    dbutils.notebook.run("./notebooks/job2",0)

terminated = is_terminated(run_id)

yetotherstuff = yetotherstuffjob(run_id)

if terminated != "Terminated" and yetothrstuff == True:
    dbutils.notebook.run("./notebooks/job3",0)

terminated = is_terminated(run_id)

finalstuff = finalstuffjob(run_id)

if terminated != "Terminated" and finalstuff == True:
    dbutils.notebook.run("./notebooks/job4",0)
    
dbutils.notebook.run("./notebooks/finaltidyupjob",0)  #this runs whatever.
```

Comment: what are otherstuffjob & finalstuffjob are doing? Can you describe the workflow at high level, as it's harder to understand the logic from the  code

Comment: I'm not in a position to do that as it would reveal information that my employer would not sanction.  Unfortunately I am unable to explain my problem clearly if you need to know what those jobs do and I'll have to work with the code I have,